# How do I get a reference to a headless fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a headless fragment to retain my data during config changes.

```
rFrag = new RetainedFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(rFrag, MODEL)
                    .commit();
```

What is the best way to access this fragment while inside of another activity or fragment besides the original activity that the headless fragment is attached to?

Using this doesn't work:

```
RetainedFragment rFrag = (RetainedFragment)getSupportFragmentManager
                            .findFragmentByTag(model);
```

I did a search and I believe this is because I don't have the retained fragment added onto the backstack, but adding a headless fragment onto the backstack isn't what I want to do.

Right now I just set the retained fragment to be public and static like this:

```
public static RetainedFragment rFrag;
```

But I feel like this isn't good practice to use static variables like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know what you mean by "headless fragment".

Secondly, I don't know what RetainedFragment() class is but I will assume that it is just a class you created that extends Fragment.

Thirdly, you can't access a Fragment through other Activity. Every fragment is attached to one Activity and when that Activity is not visible its Fragments are not accessible.

Lastly, even if you force to access by using static methods and fields and such, you are right, it is not a good practice. You can, and should, use Intent extras and Fragment arguments to pass data from one to another. You mentioned you need to retain some data, so you actually don't really need the whole Fragment, right? You can just save, load and pass around the data you need.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that other fragments can't access a fragment whose activity is not visible. Looks like I'll have to pass data around.. I knew I could do that, but it's far less convenient since they're object variables that I need to pass.

Comment: I suggest ask another question about that, then let us see what we can do for that.